# JQuery/JavaScript Get Object in Array that has attribute of specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of Objects with IDs. The Array looks something like this:

```
   var array = [
       {
           "id": 0,
           "name": "Test"
       },

       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Test2"
       },
   ]
```

I'd like to know how I could now access an object that has a specific value in their attribute. I.e. I'd like to access the object with `id = 0` or the object with `name = "Test2" and so on.

What's the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: Your objects are invalid. They property key/values should be separated by a colon, not an equals sign. See also [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays). The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method maybe useful.

Comment: @Andy You're right, sorry about that. In my code the objects were correct, I simply wrote the example wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer:

```
var array = [
   {
       "id": 0,
       "name": "Test"
   },
   {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Test2"
   },
];


console.log(array.filter(ele=>ele.id === 0));
console.log(array.filter(ele=>ele.name === 'Test2'));
```

`array.filter()` works well than `find()`.
This is because `find()` finds only 1 item according to the order of array.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is great! `find()` would've worked for what the question was intended for in this case, but I actually have a case later where I would rather need `filter()`, so knowing about both is super helpful.